# Quantmod getSymbols warning messages

Tags: r, quantmod

The following code

```
  x <- getSymbols(Symbols="RU1000TR",
                  warnings=FALSE,
                  env=NULL,
                  src="FRED")
```

always seems to return a warning message such as:

```
Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile, method, quiet, mode, cacheOK, extra) :
  downloaded length 189629 != reported length 200
```

(this happens for other symbols as well). This is an annoyance, as I cannot find a way to prevent the warning, but the actual data seems to be fine. try, tryCatch, and even sink(tmpfile, type="message") fail to catch/prevent the message as well. Since it's not fatal, is it something to live with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These warnings are thrown by `download.file`. They mean the remote file system reports a file of length 200, but a different size file was actually downloaded. They can be ignored.

You can wrap your `getSybmols` calls in `suppressWarnings` if you want to keep them from being printed to the console.

Comment: Thanks! That indeed works - I thought that I had tried it, clearly not.

Comment: @meristor: Glad it worked. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

From the warning:

```
 This message is shown once per session and may be disabled by setting 
 options("getSymbols.warning4.0"=FALSE). See ?getSymbols for more details.
```

Comment: That message is not relevant to the warning the OP is asking about.